# Julia: dollar sign in command without single quotes

Tags: julia

I am trying to run the following command from Julia:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/user/.julia/v0.3/Smile/deps/downloads
```

When I run it as-is it tries to replace $LD_LIBRARY_PATH with a local variable.
When I escape the `$`, it puts quotes around the command, which invalidates it.

```
julia> cmd = `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/tim/.julia/v0.3/Smile/deps/downloads`
ERROR: LD_LIBRARY_PATH not defined

julia> cmd = `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=\$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/tim/.julia/v0.3/Smile/deps/downloads`
`export 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/tim/.julia/v0.3/Smile/deps/downloads'`
```

I would like to run the command in a form similar to:

```
run(`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$newpath`)
```

How do I properly handle the dollar sign?

Thank you

*note: pasting the command directly into terminal and running it does work

Comment: escape it. `...=\$LD...`. no idea about julia, but since you're executing an external shell to do the export call, the shell is going to PARSE/EXPAND that variable. escaping it prevents that from happening.

Comment: no, I did try escaping it. I'll make that more clear in the question

Comment: On a related note, one can do this: `global const LIB_SMILE = find_library(["libsmilejl"], [pathtoadd])` instead of messing with LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Julia, backticks are not completely equivalent to running the corresponding command at the shell. You can't interpolate environmental variables with `$` (although `$(get(ENV, "varname", "")` should match the shell's behavior), and `export` is a shell built-in, not a command, so I don't think you can run it. Also, even if backticks shelled out, `export` would only change the environment of the subshell, not the calling process.

You should be able to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from Julia as:

```
ENV["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = "$(get(ENV, "LD_LIBRARY_PATH", "")):$newpath"
```

but you should avoid this if possible. If your intent is to `ccall` a specific library, you can pass the library path directly to `ccall`, perhaps using `find_library` as you indicated in a comment if you don't know the full path advance. If you need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` because the library needs to load other libraries, I'm not sure if there's a better way, but note that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is platform-specific. You might be able to `dlopen` the dependent libraries first, but I haven't tested that.